# Include self referecing elements on included property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a model structure as follows:

```
class A
{
    public ICollection<B> MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class B 
{
    public ICollection<B> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to include `MyProperty` as well as all `Childs`.

I tried using:

```
databaseContext.A.Include(i => i.MyProperty).ThenInclude(i => i.Childs).First();
```

But it only includes the first layer on `Childs`, how can I include all `Childs`?

Comment: are you make the relations in entities or  on `OnModelCreating` in DBContext?